# Processing SOAP response

Tags: php, soap

I am attempting to process a SOAP response from First Data's Global Gateway. I've used SoapClient before, but there is no wsdl - and the company says they do not supply one.

I've tried various other approaches such as SimpleXMLElement based on examples found here and in the PHP manual but I can't get anything to work. I suspect namespaces are part of my problem. Can anyone suggest an approach or point me to a similar example - my Google efforts have been fruitless to date.

Using PHP 5.

Partial SOAP Response (with all the HTML header stuff that precedes it stripped off) looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<SOAP-ENV:Header/>

<SOAP-ENV:Body>

<fdggwsapi:FDGGWSApiOrderResponse xmlns:fdggwsapi="http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/fdggwsapi">

<fdggwsapi:CommercialServiceProvider/>

<fdggwsapi:TransactionTime>Thu Nov 29 17:03:18 2012</fdggwsapi:TransactionTime>

<fdggwsapi:TransactionID/>

<fdggwsapi:ProcessorReferenceNumber/>

<fdggwsapi:ProcessorResponseMessage/>

<fdggwsapi:ErrorMessage>SGS-005005: Duplicate transaction.</fdggwsapi:ErrorMessage>

<fdggwsapi:OrderId>A-e833606a-5197-45d6-b990-81e52df41274</fdggwsapi:OrderId>
...

<snip>
```

I also need to be able to determine if a SOAP fault was signalled. XML for that looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:FaultX>
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="en">MerchantException</faultstring>
<detail>
cvc-pattern-valid: Value '9999185.00' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '([1-9]([0-9]{0,3}))?[0-9](\.[0-9]{1,2})?' for type '#AnonType_ChargeTotalAmount'.
cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '9999185.00' of element 'v1:ChargeTotal' is not valid.
</detail>
</SOAP-ENV:FaultX>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Using Mr. Code's answer I have been able to retrieve the data from the non-fault responses. But I need to determine what type of packet I am dealing with and extract data from both types. It would be so  much easier if only they would supply a wsdl!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your response can be parsed with SimpleXML, here's an example. Notice I am passing the namespace URL to `children()` to access the elements.

```
$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$response = $obj->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children('http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/fdggwsapi')->FDGGWSApiOrderResponse;

echo $response->TransactionTime . "\n";
echo $response->ErrorMessage;
```

**Outputs**

> Thu Nov 29 17:03:18 2012
>   SGS-005005: Duplicate transaction.

**[Codepad Demo](http://codepad.org/cxFViIPF)**

Edit: The SoapFault response can be parsed like below. It outputs the fault string and details, or 'No fault found':

```
if($obj->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/') && isset($obj->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->children()->faultcode))
{
    $fault = $obj->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->children();

    // soap fault
    echo $fault->faultstring;
    echo $fault->detail;
}
else
{
    echo 'No fault found, do normal parsing...';
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that is exactly what I needed - I had not seen an example where both namespaces were referenced like that.

Comment: The example works beautifully if I get a valid response, but I discovered an extra "wrinkle" when a soap fault is signalled. In that case there is of course no second namespace and I can't work out a simple method of determining if there is a fault element and its contents. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: Update the question with an example of the soap fault response and ill take a look.

Comment: Done - thanks so much for looking at this. With Soap Client it all seemed so much easier.

Comment: OK - I see it now - it is the triplication (is that a word?) of "children" that I was missing. It just seems strange. Thanks very much.

Comment: Making this a little clearer...
            $ns = $obj->getNamespaces(true);
            $fault = $obj->children($ns['SOAP-ENV'])->Body->children($ns['SOAP-ENV'])->children();